# Why does my WHMCS log "hashReq" in error_log

Tags: api, callback, whmcs

In WHMCS; I've installed the custom payment module: EasyPaisa works by collecting the payment information and then returning back to the site after successful/unsuccessful transaction. as soon as customer attempt to pay; WHMCS Payment module adds the following lines in the log file; but as such payment module works without issues.

```
26-Jul-2020 14:08:18 Etc/GMT] Order INFO: 1890
[26-Jul-2020 14:08:18 Etc/GMT] MAPString: amount=1.0&autoRedirect=1&emailAddr=xxxx@gmail.com&expiryDate=202032805 140818&orderRefNum=xxx&postBackURL=https://www.xxx.xxx/order/modules/gateways/callback/xxxx.php&storeId=xxxx
[26-Jul-2020 14:08:18 Etc/GMT] **hashReq**: UW12P8Dd8j5w2X9lD4QXiy9BaTc7zE3PlTDDfknMf6KFDoI02uFhaTujcoh+u0EidD2waU2LrjhCsX/IOI+BFF3s5gjTDf6K9NqkSC2sVJ6meD4KXOmbYbYZ9qvx45Cx8Y/8NfKAlZYp9fRjFV7Yg6WuN5ZUaefff/fXNqriIcbBm7PhGlJM7lbfffyjbkMK7soX1O0O5yhi8eHitAC58iUuXOLq83FNKuCdOCJLMpndlcWpfexjEbs4IN6WM3obfffZYBdXqwfEBZDx+5tERPDK+lemxMQ==
```

Comment: You're probably better off submitting a ticket to their support team.  The WHMCS tag only has a few followers on StackOverflow.

Comment: I've done that before, but 3rd party extensions are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be occurring because the developers of this module have left some `logActivity();` lines in place during the workflow these are created.

To resolve this, you simply need to look for any `logActivity` lines in the module code (If the source is unencoded) - Otherwise, reach out to the module developer and have them remove those lines.

Those lines look like they should only have been in place for debugging purposes and should not be present in a production version. Instead, you may wish to recommend to the module developers that they utilise the `logTransaction` functionality instead if these lines must be logged.

https://developers.whmcs.com/payment-gateways/callbacks/